# How to make sure app does not appear in the list of saved password?

Tags: android, passwords, appsettings, google-settings

I am working on financial android app, where security is utmost  important.
Tester has raised a bug on this app as-
whenever app is installed and user logs in, android shows the dialog "save password to google?" If user clicks yes, password is saved in googles password list and anyone who has got the phone, can see this password later.

Hence, tester wants us to do some settings in the app, so that the dialog to save the password does not appear at all after first time login.

I checked other banking/financial applications and they do not show such dialog when installed, I am not sure why our application is showing this. 
Neither these apps appears in googles list of apps/sites for which password is saved, Where as our application is listed there.

Need help on this. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's a new Android feature and you can't prevent that.

The other apps you mentioned probably using the older version of build tool.

They will upgrade to the newer version eventually and I don't recommend downgrade.

..............

If you really need to do that you shouldn't add `password` flag as your `EditText` input method.

Instead, write another editable TextView with hiding character feature (replace characters with a star for instance).
that way android can't recognize its nature which is a password.